# Group Count of values derived from a like case statement

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sql-like

I have a table has data in the format

propertyvaluestrings

userSignedwww.website.com.brxxx/sales/sold

www.website.comuser/sold

www.website.com.co.uk\sales tax on hold

What I need to do is to group by the site column from the sql below to get a total for each site

```
SELECT top 1000
      CASE
            WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.co.uk%' THEN 'UK'
            WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.us%' THEN 'USA'
            WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.com.br%' THEN 'Brazil'
            WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.co.id%' THEN 'indonesia'
            WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.com%' THEN 'Global'
       ELSE 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----Unknown'
       END as Site
    ,
    PropertyValueStrings

FROM profiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean count the number of PropertyValueStrings for each country? If so, this should work:

```
SELECT Site, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT (CASE
                WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.co.uk%' THEN 'UK'
                WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.us%' THEN 'USA'
                WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.com.br%' THEN 'Brazil'
                WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.co.id%' THEN 'indonesia'
                WHEN  propertyvaluestrings LIKE '%www.website.com%' THEN 'Global'
           ELSE 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----Unknown'
           END) AS [Site]
    ,
    propertyvaluestrings 
    FROM Profiles
) X
GROUP BY Site
```